# Keyboard misbehaviour with Firefox / Javascript after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox

After upgrading to 16.04, when I type into a javascript text field [like this search field](http://www.kijiji.ca/), every keystroke erases the one before it.  I've also noticed subtly different behaviour in the location bar; matching URLs are no longer pre-selected until I cursor down.

I have removed my entire ~/.mozilla directory, purged firefox* (and manually deleted all the hanging firefox files in /etc and /usr/lib).

Even after what should be a completely fresh install of Firefox 49.0 (and a short try with an early v48 build), the problem persists.  The only way I can make the behaviour stop is to disable javascript in about:config.

Possibly related: when I attempted to post this question with Firefox, the post hung, and I got an error from StackExchange about an unusually high number of requests.

Anyone else seeing anything similar?  What else can I try?

UPDATE:

It's more than just Firefox.  All gecko-based applications seem to be misinterpreting keyboard input, as was Eclipse.  I suspect keystrokes were going to the wrong windows, somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a week of fiddling, I gave up and deleted `~/.config`.  That fixed my specific problem, but it sure would've been nice to actually solve the problem.  Marking solved, but if you figure it out, please post a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Alt-Gr key not working properly on Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973551/alt-gr-key-not-working-properly-on-firefox/987131#987131)

The solution is, to activate the checkbox `Prevent accessibility services from accessing` your browser in Firefox settings under `Privacy & Security` -> `Permissions`

Comment: Can't accept (no way to test) but it's always good to have other options to test for next time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A better workaround is to disable IBus, as described at the bottom of this thread https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1484157

> As said on the ubuntu-fr forum, you could avoid the bug by going in
>   system option ▸ languages ▸ Input keyboard system and selecting an
>   option other than IBus.
>   (https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2020851)

Comment: Can't test it until next time it happens, but your answer seems plausible.  Have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and deleting ~/.config/dconf solved it.

Comment: This is really poor answer. You need to provide good answer with more information.

Comment: I disagree.  It would benefit from more info, but even without, it is potentially useful to others to know that it may not be necessary to delete all of .config/