# Alt-Gr key not working properly with Firefox menus

Tags: keyboard, firefox, firefox-extensions, lastpass

When using Firefox I have troubles with the use of Alt-Gr inside an open menu window (address bar, search bar, addon popup).

This is particularly annoying since, for instance, when using LastPass I cannot enter my email because the window gets closed as soon as I press Alt-Gr (I need it to type the @ sign).

I tried Safe Mode as well as previous Firefox versions, the problem doesn't fix.

The issue came out after updating some package (apt-get upgrade)
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, (with a Spanish keyboard layout)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this as an answer for future reference.

The problem was probably due to a bug of the same LastPass addon,
so it was automatically fixed with the following update.

In case this issue will happen again in the future, I suggest to downgrade the addon, or simply wait for the next update.

EDIT: Given the fact I suffered from the same issue (again) even without any addon installed, I must deduce the bug is actually within Firefox itself.

Answer (score 1):

The solution should be, to activate the checkbox `Prevent accessibility services from accessing your browser` in Firefox settings under `Privacy & Security` -> `Permissions`

Comment: I'm suffering this problem right now. Tried your solution but nothing changed. Thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: I have the problem on all my machine, but you are right! I've detected, that I have to make this setting on each restart/reboot.