# Weird typing problem in Firefox 57

Tags: keyboard, firefox

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Firefox 57 and for some reason certain text boxes in Firefox (like Gmail) don't allow me to type with ALT. Every time I type something with the addition of ALT, the text cursor (caret) goes backwards.

I've already tried all the solutions Google could find regarding issues like this, but it seems this is something different than what people in the past meant. For example, it's not a touchpad issue.

At first, I thought it's a problem with Polish characters, but then I checked with the English keyboard settings and it was the same. I have no idea what's going on here, especially since it works in some text fields (like this). It's so annoying. Please, help me with this. I don't want to spend a week searching for a possible solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How do I downgrade Firefox v. 57 to v. 56?" question](https://askubuntu.com/q/977138/66509).

Comment: I don't want to downgrade to Firefox 56. Firefox 57 is a great release, other than this weird issue.

Comment: Could you give an example of a site I can test that does this, I don't have access to (your) Gmail. I assume you mean the compose key "AltGr" (or "right Alt")? Perhaps you need to specify a key sequence too as I'm not used to typing in foreign languages. For example "AltGr+S gives me ß". Perhaps you're getting a unicode marker inserted by accident?

Comment: ***Any*** letter key pressed with AltGr moves the caret backwards in certain text boxes. For example, Gmail's  and Twitter's message boxes.

Comment: No help whatsoever? I really can't find any answer to this.  :(

Comment: The latest Firefox update didn't fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a duplicate of this issue: [Keyboard misbehaviour with Firefox / Javascript after upgrade to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836228/keyboard-misbehaviour-with-firefox-javascript-after-upgrade-to-16-04?rq=1)

Just like DS Justice, I didn't find an actual solution, but deleting ~/.config worked for me as well.

EDIT: The issue came back on the next day. Can somebody find a true fix?

Answer (score 0):

A better workaround is to disable IBus, as described at the bottom of this thread https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1484157

> As said on the ubuntu-fr forum, you could avoid the bug by going in
>   system option ▸ languages ▸ Input keyboard system and selecting an
>   option other than IBus.
>   (https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2020851)